# Simplify the expression $(a^2)^5(2x^2)^4\over2^5(a^3)^3(x^3)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Can anybody please provide a step by step solution to the following expression ?

> $$(a^2)^5(2x^2)^4\over2^5(a^3)^3(x^3)^2$$

Comment: $\LaTeX$ tutorial: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: That's not an equation

Comment: $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$. You'd have, for example, $(a^2)^5 = a^{10}$. Also, $\frac{a^b}{a^c} = a^{b-c}.$ Maybe you should pick up from here.

Comment: That is a expression not a equation. Use laws of indices to solve it.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I meant not solution but to SIMPLIFY.

Comment: @Anonymous What you mean by solution ? Do you mean to reduce the expression to simplest form ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  $(a^2)^5 = a^{2 \cdot 5} = a^{10}.$

Another hint:

$$\frac{a^8}{a^5} = a^{8-5} = a^3.$$

Your expression is

$$(a^2)^5(2x^2)^4\over2^5(a^3)^3(x^3)^2$$

By applying the first hint, you arrived at this expression in the comments:

$$\frac{a^{10} \cdot 16 x^8}{32 \cdot a^9 x^6}$$

Comment: I already knew that part. So I was able to do some of it.

Comment: (a^2)^5(2x^2)^4/2^5(a^3)^3(x^3)^2=a^10(16x^8)25(a^9)(x^6)

Comment: What I don't get is how to continue. What parts do I divide?

Comment: Ok, so for example, do I start to subtract the exponents of the same terms? So a^10-a^9=a^1. Isn't that it?

Comment: Edited my answer.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Regarding $a^1$, yes, that's correct.  Then do the same with the $x$'s, and with the numbers.  The main point is that you know all of the $a$'s represent the same number (whatever it is, as long as it's not zero!) so you can "cancel out" the $a$'s.  Same with the $x$'s, you can cancel $x$'s with $x$'s.  But $a$ and $x$ aren't, in general, the same, so you can't cancel an $a$ with an $x$.

Comment: Now 16x^8-x^6 makes 16x^2. And we can't do the rest because there are no like terms left.

Comment: You have $2^5 = 32$ on the bottom.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I mixed it up with 5^2. How foolish.

Comment: I still don't get it.

Comment: Still don't get it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40865/discussion-between-john-and-anonymous).

Answer (score 0):

First will show you laws of indices :-

$$a^n * a^m = a^{m+n}$$
$$\frac{a^n}{a^m} = a^{n-m}$$
$$a^n * b^n = (ab)^n$$
$$\frac{a^n}{b^n} = (\frac{a}{b})^n$$
$$(a^n)^m= a^{m*n}$$

Now we will solve your $expression$ with these laws.

> $$(a^2)^5(2x^2)^4\over2^5(a^3)^3(x^3)^2$$
>   $$\frac{(a^{10})(16x^{8})}{32(a^9)(x^6)} \cdots \rightarrow (a^n)^m= a^{m*n}$$
>   $$\frac{(a^1)(x^{2})}{2} \cdots \rightarrow \frac{a^n}{a^m} = a^{n-m}$$
>   $$(a)(x^{2})\over2$$

Simple nah.

Comment: How did you do the part where you subtracted the exponents?

Comment: @Anonymous check the law i have listed on the side. Eg:- $2^5\over2^7$ then by using that law i can do $1\over2^{7-5}$ which is $1\over4$, if you have a doubt check it in calculator.

Comment: I know how you goot a^1 since a^10-9=a^1 but how did you get x^2 and 2?

Comment: @Anonymous Why ? $x^8\over x^6$ = $x^{8-6}$ = $x^2$ and $16\over32$ = $1\over2$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac {(a^2)^5(2x^2)^4}{2^5(a^3)^3(x^3)^2}  = \frac {a^{10}16x^8}{32a^9x^6} =0.5ax^{2}$$ as for the laws on how to perform this see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Identities_and_properties