# Express $(100^3)^5$ with a base of $10$

Tags: exponentiation

Express $(100^3)^5$ with a base of $10$. I don't get this.

Comment: They are asking you to express the given quantity as $10^b$, for suitable $b$.

Comment: So I replace 100 as 10?

Comment: As a start to finding $b$, note that $100=10^2$, so we are looking at $((10^2)^3)^5$. Now find $b$ using laws of exponentiation.

Comment: That would equal (100)^3)^5=(100000)^5 ... big number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's combine the exponents by using the rule $(x^a)^b = x^{a\cdot b}.$ Thus we have $$(100^3)^5 = 100^{3 \cdot 5} = 100^{15}.$$ Next, we note that $100 = 10^2$. So we replace $100$ in the above equation with $10^2$ and apply the same rule.$$100^{15} = (10^2)^{15} = 10^{2\cdot 15} = 10^{30}.$$ Thus, we've expressed it with base 10. Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: I'm posting more questions on this site soon. For example,

Comment: Can anybody please provide a step by step solution to the following expression ?



(a 2 ) 5 (2x 2 ) 4 2 5 (a 3 ) 3 (x 3 ) 2

Comment: Never mind. Just look at this link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1817725/simplify-the-expression-a252x24-over25a33x32# I'm still stuck on it.

Comment: Go ahead and post them, if this is satisfactory for this particular question please mark it as an accepted solution!

Comment: Up votes are appreciated too! They allow users to offer bounties on their questions and get them answered quicker. I'm checking out your other question now!

Answer (score 0):

It means going for this representation
$$
(100^3)^5 = 10^x \quad (*)
$$
The left hand side is 
$$
(100^3)^5 =100^{15} = (10^2)^{15} = 10^{30}
$$
Or we take the logarithm of both sides of $(*)$:
$$
\ln((100^3)^5) = \ln(10^x) \iff \\
5 \ln(100^3) = 15 \ln(100) = x \ln(10) \iff \\
x = 15 \ln(100)/\ln(10) = 30 \ln(10)/\ln(10) = 30
$$